# Texts of Shirei HaYichud Online

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, internet, song-poetry, rabbi-yehudah-hechasid

Does anyone know where to find a copy of the shirei hayichud online with cut-and-paste capability? I've checked piyut.org.il and HebrewBooks.org, however the only copies I found were with horrible OCR or grainy scans.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to [Service of the Synagogue by the Hebrew Publishing Company](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33442&st=&pgnum=83&hilite=).

Here is a link to [Yom Rishon](http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=2508) that you can cut and paste.

Comment: Thanks Gershon, but my attempts to cut-and-paste *Az b'yom Shabbat* were met with letters in orders that only a mekubal or a game-theorist could understand.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt, then the first sentence of your question should specify that you want a copy-pastable copy. This answers your question (as asked) perfectly.

Comment: @msh210, he did complain about "horrible OCR" which would imply copy-paste (I can't think of any other reason why you would want that, anyway).

Comment: @Yishai Searchability?